# Нужен контейнер динамический принимающий любые типы данных

Tags: c++, visual-c++

задача следующего характера:
Нужен динамический массив, который может принимать в себя данные любых типов, например, как vector.push_back, но любые типы.
Мне нужно сделать сериализацию данных в этот самый массив, который умеет принимать в себя любые данные, как массив.

Мне это нужно, чтобы не создавать постоянно массив таким образом:
[CLANG]
char buffer[1024];
WriteInt4(buffer, 50)
WriteString(buffer, "hello")

foo(buffer.str(), buffer.lenght) 
[/CLANG]
И данные перед вызовом foo будут таким образом (данные в таком порядке, переворчивать не нужно): 
00 00 00 32 48 65 6c 6c 6f 00

Собственно, как быть? Я слышал что есть std::any, но я без понятия, то ли это, что я пытаюсь найти.
boost не хочу использовать.

Еще видел вот такой код, вроде похоже на то, что нужно, но он неудобен (не реклама): qaru.site/questions/7005490/possibility-of-store-object-type-for-stdany

Как быть? Мне нужен такой контейнер, который бы поддерживал вывод данных, как массив и чтоб этот массив заполнянся в том порядке, в каком я буду пихать в него данные.

Comment: На всякий случай: Вы же понимаете, что этот `qaru`, на который вы сослались, просто автоматически переводит контент с английского SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705978/possibility-of-store-object-type-for-stdany

Comment: Вам точно нужно *хранить* в массиве любые типы данных? Может сделать обертку над `std::vector<unsigned char>` с перегруженным/шаблонным `push_back`, который будет сериализовывать переданные объекты во внутренний вектор, или это не подойдет?

Comment: Я не знаю ребята, я вообще не спец С++, мне просто нужно создать поток данных и запихать его в массив, а использовать стандартный char array[size] не хочется. Есть ли вариант более комфортный и быстрый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::any> vector_of_any_object;
vector_of_any_object.push_back(std::string("String object"));
vector_of_any_object.push_back(5);
vector_of_any_object.push_back(MySuperObject());

for (const auto& obj : vector_of_any_object) 
{
    const std::type_info& type = obj.type();
    if (type == typeid(std::string)) {
        std::string& string_ref = std::any_cast<std::string&>(obj);
        string_ref = "new string"; // заменить текст в строке, которая хранится в vector_of_any_object
    } else if (type == typeid(int)) {
    } ...
}
```

P.S. Если C++17 не доступен, то используй boost::any, если не хочешь тащить boost, то вытащи реализацию boost::any к себе, она не большая.

Comment: Мне вытаскивать из него данные не требуется, нужно только пихать и передавать сразу. 

Как чистить этот вектор после send ?

Comment: Кстати, какой метод будет быстрее? Использовать вектор или стандартный статический массив? Я так понял, обычный массив быстрее и данные очищать не требуется, но меня интересует, насколько сильно уступает вектор обычному массиву

Comment: @Дан Куда передовать? Если по сети, то тебе в любом случае нужен сериализатор обхектов в байтовую последовательность, тогда и std::any не нужен, т.к. можно сразу в std::vector<char> складывать.